# SortableTableView Header Cannot Be Clicked inside of ViewPager2's Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm currently making a java project for android and I have a ViewPager2 class, Inside one of it's fragments. I use the SortableTableView Library to make a sortable table. The dataclicked function worked just fine but the TableHeaderClickListener won't work. When clicked, it looks like the whole header was clicked and not the column. So the TableHeaderClickListener function didn't get called.

But when I changed ViewPager2 Into the old ViewPager it works completely fine, is there something I'm missing in ViewPager2?